# PHP : set client base URL with singleton

Tags: php, singleton

So, I want to create a client base URL with singleton.

This is my GuzzleClient.php which is containing the base URL

```
<?php

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

class GuzzleClient {
    public static function getClient()
    {
        static $client = null;
        if (null === $client) 
        {
            $client = new Client([
                'base_url' => 'http://localhost:8080/task_manager/v1/',
            ]);
        }

        return $client;
    }


    private function __construct() 
    {}
}
```

And this one is where I should put the base url

```
require_once 'GuzzleClient.php';

class CardTypeAPIAccessor 
{

    private $client;

    public function __construct($client) 
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function getCardTypes() {
        $cardTypes = array();

        try 
        {
            //this is where base URL should be
            $response = $client->get('admin/card/type',
                ['headers' => ['Authorization' => $_SESSION['login']['apiKey']]
            ]);

            $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
            // Check that the request is successful.
            if ($statusCode == 200) 
            {
                $error = $response->json();
                foreach ($error['types'] as $type) 
                {
                    $cardType = new CardType();
                    $cardType->setId($type['card_type_id']);
                    $cardType->setCategory($type['category']);

                    array_push($cardTypes, $cardType);
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

I stuck with how to put the method in GuzzleClient into this code.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inharit` `GuzzleClient` class into `CardTypeAPIAccessor`, and check if `$client` is not`instanceof` `GuzzleClient` then assign access object into `$this->client`

```
class CardTypeAPIAccessor extends GuzzleClient
{
    private $client;

    public function __construct($client) 
    {
      if($client instanceof GuzzleClient){
          $this->client = $client              
      }else{
          $this->client = parent::getClient();

      }  


    }
}
```

Comment: new error appeared, it said :"Undefined variable: client" in this code  

`$response = $client->get('admin/card/type',
                ['headers' => ['Authorization' => $_SESSION['login']['apiKey']]
            ]);`

Comment: use `$this->client` variable instead of `$client` for call `get()` method

Comment: I got new error, it said :  Undefined variable: client on this code  `$cardTypeAPIAccessor = new CardTypeAPIAccessor($client);`

Answer (score 1):

I'm creating an abstract class for my webservices that send requests. The instance of guzzle is created in a singleton file:

```php
use Guzzle\Http\Client;

class GuzzleSingleton
{
    private static $_instance = null;
    private static $baseUrl = '';

    public static function getBaseUrl(): string
    {
        return self::$baseUrl;
    }

    private static function setBaseUrl($baseUrl): void
    {
        self::$baseUrl = $baseUrl;
    }

    public static function getInstance(string $apiUrl, ?int $apiPort, string $apiSuffix): ?Client
    {
        if (is_null(self::$_instance)) {
            self::buildApiUrl($apiUrl, $apiPort, $apiSuffix);
            self::$_instance = new Client(self::getBaseUrl());
        } else {
            self::buildApiUrl($apiUrl, $apiPort, $apiSuffix);
            self::$_instance->setBaseUrl(self::getBaseUrl());
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

    private static function buildApiUrl(string $apiUrl, ?int $apiPort, string $apiSuffix): void
    {
        $apiDns = rtrim($apiUrl, '/');
        $urlApi = (!is_null($apiPort)) ? sprintf('%s:%d', $apiDns, $apiPort) : $apiUrl;

        $urlApi .= $apiSuffix;
        self::setBaseUrl($urlApi);
    }

}
```

My abstract class:

```php
abstract class AbstractWebservice
{
    public function __construct(string $apiUrl, ?int $apiPort, ?string $apiSuffixUrl, Session $session)
    {
        $this->setApiUrl($apiUrl);
        $this->setApiPort($apiPort);
        $this->setApiSuffixUrl($apiSuffixUrl);
        $this->session = $session;

        $this->buildFactory();
    }

    public function buildFactory(): void
    {
        $this->guzzleWs = GuzzleSingleton::getInstance($this->getApiUrl(), $this->getApiPort(), $this->getApiSuffixUrl());
    }

    public function sendRequest(string $endpoint, ?array $body, ?array $options, string $method)
    {
        $request = $this->guzzleWs->createRequest($method, $endPoint, self::$headers, $body, $options);
        return $request->send();
    }

   
}
```